# Запятая должна стоять до «и» или выделять с двух сторон «конечно же»?

Tags: запятые

Один из сильнейших, и конечно же самых разрушительных, это Пиро элемент, который способен поджигать противников, вызывая продолжительное горение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Как вариант:**

*Один из сильнейших и, **конечно же**, самых разрушительных, это **Пиро-элемент,** который способен поджигать противников, вызывая продолжительное горение.*

**Пояснение**

1. **Однородные** отношения: один из сильнейших и самых разрушительных. Обособление **вводного** слова "конечно же".
2. **Варианты записи**: Пиро-элемент, элемент Пиро, также элемент Pyro.

**Примечание**

*Персонажи с элементом Pyro (Огонь) могут произвести огненный взрыв, который наносит урон противникам в течение долгого времени или поджигает окружающее пространство*. *[Из статьи](https://lionadegames.com/ru/chto-takoe-elemental-burst-genshin-impact/)*

Comment: Sharon, а что насчёт запятой перед "это"?

Comment: Хотите тире поставить?)  А подчеркнутая пауза необязательна в таких случаях.  Здесь можно обособить  определительный оборот  в препозиции перед пиро-элементом, а "это" считать указательным местоимением.  Авторский  выбор вида синтаксической конструкции.

Comment: Это еще и от контекста зависит.  Скорее всего, дается какой-то обзор элементов, поэтому предложение с запятой нормально смотрится.

Comment: Да я просто спрашиваю... плюс поставил. Обычно не вызывает сомнений постановка тире перед "это", и независимо от характера паузы, так принято. Я это предложение воспринимаю так, как будто перед ним говорится о каких-то предметах-элементах, и здесь в первой части это существительное опущено. Получается тире ставится между подразумеваемым подлежащим с его определениями и сказуемым. На указательное местоимение, думаю, совсем не похоже. // Для меня с запятой ненормально смотрится...

Comment: А я представляю текст  так) Элементы бывают разные.  Если выделять самый сильнейший и разрушительный, то это Пиро-элемент.

Comment: Вы применили синтаксическую синонимию, но ведь это не значит, что знаки в разных структурах будут те же. С запятой в изначальном предложении получаются какие-то два отдельных сообщения. Говорю, у меня не вяжется ни зрительно, ни смыслово. // Ладно, спокойной ночи.

Comment: Помните предложения:   (1) Первое, что меня удивило,  (так) это пассажиры  (тире и запятая как варианты).  (2) Кто хорош, так это Солженицын.  Что-то есть между ними общее. Называется признак,  а потом указывается   предмет (это), который обладает этим признаком. Но это всего лишь мое мнение/наблюдение, а не что-то претендующее на истину. Здесь похожая структура